# Solution of the 2D stationary diffusion equation

Tags: probability, differential-equations, diffusion

I'm trying to find the solution to the 2D stationary diffusion equation

$$-D\nabla^2P(\vec{\rho_2})=\delta(\vec{\rho_1}-\vec{\rho_2})$$

where $\vec{\rho}=(x,y)$ and $D$ is the diffusion coefficient.

Help would be very much appreciated. Also, I'd be happy to get some references as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I  assume that your sign is correct: that there is a *sink* rather than a *source* at ${\bf r}_2$?

Then this  is standard result from  electrostatics --- the potential of a line charge:
$$
P({\bf r}_1, {\bf r}_2)= \frac 1{2\pi D} \ln (\mu|{\bf r}_1- {\bf r}_2|),
$$
where $\mu$ is a constant that it is not determined by your equation. You need to specify the radius $\mu^{-1}$ at which $P$ becomes zero. This has to be bigger than zero for a solution to exist.

Comment: Hi Mike, and thanks for the answer. Is this the 2D solution? Does $\vec{r}$ have a $z$ component as well?

Comment: I was intending ${\bf r}$ to be two dimensional. In three D with a line sink on the $z$ axis,  $|r_1-r_2|$ should be the radial distance from the sink, ie the $r$ in cylindrical polar coordinates.

Comment: I just noticed that I messed up the sign. Clearly there should be a negative sign before the diffusion coefficient. Is this the solution to the corrected equation (with the negative sign before D)?

Comment: Feels like this solution still holds if, say, I define $W=-P$.

Comment: Yes. That's why I asked if there was a sink rather than a source at the origin. Just change the sign of $P$ and you are OK.